# Initiate file download in browser from JavaScript

Tags: javascript, download

I want to initiate a file download from react, such that the browser downloads it as any regular file.

When I use [fetch](https://github.com/matthew-andrews/isomorphic-fetch), I can download the file and do what I want, but is not downloaded with  the browsers download manager. The files are rather large, that is why I want the browser to manage the download.

Comment: Do you have the URL to the file you want to download?

Comment: Yes, i have the full URL. I might need authentcation Headers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I asked you if you have the full URL to the file.
If you want to start the download from a link, use the solution Kielstra provided. If you want to start the download using javascript, use the following code:

```
window.location = url_to_file;
```

Comment: In typescript one would do: window.location.href = url_to_file;

Comment: Wouldn't this solution be a problem for some files (e.g. text/html), in some cases instead of downloading the file it may just open the file in the browser.

Comment: True, but there was no context provided to know what kind of file this would be. Also, this is marked as the answer so it helped Nathan.

Answer (score 2):

If you have the URL to the file that you want to be downloaded, you can simply create a link to it with the `download` attribute.

```
<a href="link_to_file" download>Download</a>
```

Comment: This isn't supported on all browsers but might be an option to some: https://caniuse.com/#feat=download